# Using Before() in @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Tags: cypress

I am new to Cucumber testing. I have a starter test which works ok, but I need to clear down the database in between tests.

This is the scenario:

```js
Scenario: Should update the stock levels
 Given user is on the product page
 When user updates the stock quantity
 Then the new stock quantity is available on the product page
```

How do I handle cleardown for the the database in Cucumber? I've seen the recipe [Seeding Your Database in Node](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/server-communication__seeding-database-in-node) but how do I implement that in Cucumber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few places to call the task.

If using the Mocha `beforeEach()`, it will run first - ahead of the Cucumber methods.

You can also import Cucumber `Before()` which is a wrapper around the Mocha hook and runs **after** the `beforeEach()` call.

Or you could call the database seed task at the start of the `Given()` method.

```js
import { When, Then, Before, Given } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";

beforeEach(() => {
  // reset database
  cy.fixture('dbdata.json').then(data => {
    cy.task('seed:db', data)
  })
})

Before(() => {
  // reset database
  cy.fixture('dbdata.json').then(data => {
    cy.task('seed:db', data)
  })
})

Given('user is on the product page', () => {
  // reset database
  cy.fixture('dbdata.json').then(data => {
    cy.task('seed:db', data)
  })
  cy.visit(...)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In your step file, you can just add a `beforeEach()` hook exactly as you would in a non-cucumber Cypress test.

```js
import { Given, When, Then } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";

beforeEach(() => {
  // reset database
  cy.fixture('my-data.json').then(data => {
    cy.task('seed:db', data)
  })
})

Given('user is on the product page', () => {
  ...
})
```